# Selenium launches Firefox but does not connect to it

Tags: c#, azure, firefox, selenium

**Context**: Microsoft Azure; VS2015 Community; C#; Selenium.WebDriver.2.52.0; FirefoxPortableLegacy35; Console (i.e. *not running under IIS*)

```
        var seleniumProxy = new Proxy(); 
        seleniumProxy.HttpProxy = "localhost:" + port;

        ...

        FirefoxBinary fb = new FirefoxBinary(@"E:\DevTools\FirefoxPortableLegacy35\App\Firefox\firefox.exe");
        FirefoxProfileManager fpm = new FirefoxProfileManager();
        FirefoxProfile fp = fpm.GetProfile("webserver");
        fp.DeleteAfterUse = false;
        fp.SetProxyPreferences(seleniumProxy);
        IWebDriver wd = null;
        try
        {
            wd = new FirefoxDriver(fb, fp);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(exc.Message);
        }
```

(The `port` is being provided by BrowserMob Proxy.)

The `webserver` profile is defined in `C:\Users\Bruce\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\profiles.ini` as

```
        [General]
        StartWithLastProfile=1

        [Profile0]
        Name=default
        IsRelative=1
        Path=Profiles/eracklz4.default

        [Profile1]
        Name=webserver
        IsRelative=1
        Path=Profiles/webserver.default
```

`ExistingProfiles` in the `FirefoxProfileManager` lists `webserver` so the `fpm` var is not null.

Firefox 3.5.19 launches. However, Selenium times out after 45 seconds with the message:

```
Exception thrown: 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' in WebDriver.dll
Failed to start up socket within 45000 milliseconds. Attempted to connect to the following addresses: 127.0.0.1:7055
```

I have studied most of the previous postings on this subject. However, many are in the context of IIS. This is a console app.

Where I am going wrong with this?

**LATER**

I should have tried installing the latest Firefox. It installed a WebDriver extension and now I can talk to Firefox.

Sigh ...

Comment: What is the Azure service that your console is running on/as? WebJob, Cloud Service, VM?

Comment: VM, if I recall correctly. I RDP into it as if were a desktop.